# Full Stack Architecture using CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-cloudfront, react-fullstack

I am trying to build the architecture for a full stack web app which will be hosted on AWS.

Up until now, I decided that I want to serve the front-end using a **CDN (AWS CloudFront)** in order to optimize the latency for users all over the world.

My question is: How should I manage the backend deployment in order to have the least latency when getting HTTP requests from the frontend?

1. Should I have multiple **Load Balancers** in different zones that will stay in front of my backend API?
2. Should I have an **AWS Global Accelerator** instead of LBs & a bunch of EC2 instances in different zones?

Currently, those are the 2 options that I was thinking about, but if there is a better way to do it, I am open for recommendations.

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on how you plan to configure CloudFront, but if you use the default settings, CloudFront is already global. So that would mean you probably do not need the Global Accelerator. ALBs are highly available by design, so they will be deployed in as many AZs as you wish. Last but not the least, unless you are creating an app for millions of users, you probably do not need to worry that much about latency.

Comment: Ok, got it. And if I have let's say 3 LBs (US, EU, Asia), the CDN will know (based on user location) to which LB to send the backend request in order to have the least latency, right?